# Is gstreamer the best encoder for vorbis or is there a better encoding engine I should use?

Tags: software-recommendation, gstreamer, encoding, cd-ripping, ogg-vorbis

I have sound juicer installed and I want to rip to vorbis.ogg. Is gstreamer the best encoder for vorbis or is there a  better encoding engine I should use.

The default gstreamer profile is

```
audio/x-raw-float,rate=44100,channels=2 ! vorbisenc name=enc quality=0.5 ! oggmux
```

I am going to raise the quality to 0.7 but thats all nothing if gstreamer isn't the best encoder.

Any suggestions for high quality ripping?

Edit: a good answer to this will also be the top search result in google for "best vorbis encoding engine".

Double Edit: It appears oggenc itself is the best encoder which rules out using sound juicer to rip cd's as it uses gstreamer. I have installed oggenc and am testing the command ripper abcde. Found a good configuration for it here [oggenc config for abcde](http://www.andrews-corner.org/abcde.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people prefer an AoTuV tuned oggenc & in some cases the shared vorbis libs.

If you're on 11.04 or higher it's quite simple in a number of ways, eariler than 11.04 requires some workarounds.

This thread in UF concerns this over a period of time, there are methods for 10.04 thru 11.10 though 10.04 & 10.10 haven;t been updated for current AoTuV

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1137670

For the moment just concerning **11.04/11.10 & probably 12.04**

The easiest method is in **post 40**, it builds new shared libvorbis* & replaces your current ones in /usr. You can use your current oggenc & likely a gstreamer encoder thru libvorbis*. Very simple to do.

An alternate method is to build a static AoTuV to /usr/local & then also build vorbis-tools off of it. This provides an oggenc that has built-in AoTuV support & provides static libs/headers for vlc/ffmpeg if building those. Myself prefer the latter method for various reasons.

So for the latter method i'll copy here, currently **post 61**

To start **remove your current vorbis-tools package**, then open  a terminal

```
sudo apt-get  build-dep libvorbis vorbis-tools
```

.

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

This is 1 complete command, copy & paste

```
cd 
mkdir -p ogg_build && cd ogg_build && \
wget http://www.geocities.jp/aoyoume/aotuv/source_code/libvorbis-aotuv_b6.03.tar.bz2 && \
tar -xvjf libvorbis-aotuv_b6.03.tar.bz2 && \
cd aotuv-b6.03_20110424 && chmod +x configure && \
./configure --disable-shared && make && \
sudo checkinstall --pkgname=aotuv-vorbis  --backup=no --default \
--deldoc=yes -deldesc=yes --delspec=yes --fstrans=no --pkgversion=6.03
```

Finish up with, again one command

```
cd
cd ogg_build
apt-get source vorbis-tools && \
cd vorbis-tools-1.4.0 && ./configure && make && \
sudo checkinstall --backup=no --deldoc=yes  --deldesc=yes --delspec=yes \
--default --fstrans=no  --pkgversion 1.4.0+aotuv-b6.3
```

If you have no intention of building ffmpeg and or vlc then you can now remove the aotuv-vorbis package, it's no longer needed, *the first package built

Use oggenc as normal or thru apps that use it like abcde, rubyripper,  soundkonverter

oggenc --help can prove useful, use ogginfo /path to whatever.ogg to ck.

Ex. from simple -q 9 parameter -

```
ogginfo '/home/doug/Music/luckynight.ogg' 
Processing file "/home/doug/Music/luckynight.ogg"...

New logical stream (#1, serial: 6e5e6d64): type vorbis
Vorbis headers parsed for stream 1, information follows...
Version: 0
Vendor: AO; aoTuV [20110424] (based on Xiph.Org's libVorbis)
Channels: 2
Rate: 44100

Nominal bitrate: 320.000000 kb/s
Upper bitrate not set
Lower bitrate not set
Vorbis stream 1:
Total data length: 2489270 bytes
Playback length: 1m:00.479s
Average bitrate: 329.268519 kb/s
Logical stream 1 ended
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed instructions. yes I had read about aotuv vorbis. Not sure if this would resolve as well as your instructions but I found a current ppa by Tobias Wolf with aotuv musepack and libtheora all patched. it is here https://launchpad.net/~towolf/+archive/codecs

Comment: The ppa would do fine

Comment: I have to try to remember not to hit enter on comments... - what I was going to also add is that the ppa is using an older version of AoTuV, (5.6), but for those not wishing to build it is a decent alternative

Comment: I did the build instructions you posted and they worked well. Just curius regarding the PPA.

Comment: @doug Works nicely for Xenial as well :)